# How to undo an 'erase' action in adobe photoshop 7.0?

Tags: adobe, photoshop, undo, erase

Ctrl+Z does 'undo' only for the last performed action in Adobe Photoshop 7.0. How to undo an 'erase' action done a while ago,I mean,an erase done before a few other actions to edit the photo?

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the history..
or for simpler action.. The undo for PS is Ctrl + Alt + Z

Read about `Using the History panel` at this link:
https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/undo-history.html

Answer (score 1):

Use mask to that layer, this will help you to undo erase any time. You will just have to use brush in mask layer

black color brush= erase
white color brush = undo the same

If you use soft brush, it will be like soft eraser

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to step backward instead of undo  :

- CTRL + ALT + Z